# How can I implement remove icon on image after selecting it from image picker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Anyone have an idea about remove icon on the image after selecting it from image picker?
if yes,please let me know..
thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "remove icon on image" ? Please provide more specifications about what you want to achieve

Comment: you can see the cross icon on image, I am talking about that.

Comment: Ok. lets say you have a list of images you can simply remevove item at clicked position.byCalling yourList.removeIndex(clickedIndex).If you provide code i can give you more hel about it